# Differences between a custom NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx in a SharePoint 2007 List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm working in a list with a custom NewForm.aspx and a custom EditForm.aspx, which I've called New.aspx and Edit.aspx. I'm far from a SharePoint expert, but it looks like the only differences between the two files are the miscellaneous ControlMode attributes set throughout the file.

ControlMode="New" for New.aspx and ControlMode="Edit" for Edit.aspx

As a test, I took the code from my New.aspx and copied it into my Edit.aspx and just changed the ControlMode attributes to 'Edit.' Everything seems to be working fine. So what I'd like to do is just use one file rather than a separate one for New and Edit. I'm not sure if this is possible, but the first step I took was to create an XSL variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="ControlMode" select="'Edit'" />
```

Then I can do something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$ControlMode = 'New'">
    <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$ControlMode = 'Edit'">
    <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

My form is still working fine at this point, but it's still two different files. So the question is, does anyone know a way I can populate the xsl:variable dynamically so that I can specify just one file for new and edit modes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if answering my own question is correct etiquette or not, but I found my answer... turns out to be much simpler than I thought.

As I was reading Brian's reply, it occurred to me that editing a post changes the query string. There's an ID specified of course. So I started looking for the best way to parse the query string. That's when I realized that this is already done for me in the ParameterBindings:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

The xsl:param tag was not specified however, so I added this to the top of my xsl:stylesheet:

```
<xsl:param name="ListItemId"></xsl:param>
```

Then, instead of using the ControlMode variable that I created in my original post, I can now test directly against the ListItemID:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$ListItemId = '0' or not($ListItemId)">
    <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Basically, I'm just checking for a 0 value (the default specified in the ParameterBinding) and showing different controls.

I've been testing this for a bit this afternoon, and thus far it works brilliantly.

Comment: i'd change that to &gt; 0 instead of two conditionals. What if they supply a -1?

Comment: There shouldn't be a case of a -1 since the edit links are created from the list itself. Unless of course someone manually changes the value in the querystring, which is entirely possible. But yes, reversing the logic and checking for a greater than zero value makes more sense and is easier to read as well. Thanks!

Comment: Wow this is very interesting! I never thought about creating one reusable form for some reason...

Comment: For my purposes I just can't see a reason to have the new and update files separate. I'm sure there are cases where you might want your edit form to be different though. Anyway, I've got some updates to make to the answer. I found a couple other things I need to change. As soon as I get all the kinks worked out, I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

the built in sharepoint controls will attempt to function differently based on the control mode defined. Obviously if it is edit, then it will attempt to not only just render a control but populated that control with the current value. If the mode is new, it will simply render the control without a predefined value. There's a lot more to it but that's the high level overview.

If you are using custom new vs edit form I'd personally keep them seperate for the organizational purposes. An easy solution would be to use an XSL include after you have defined the variable inside each pages form.

Comment: Thanks Brian - I'm going back and forth with keeping them seperate. But as of right now, the files are identical. I don't do anything different in the New.aspx vs the Edit.aspx. My hope was to be able to change that xsl:variable dynamically depending on whether i was editing an existing item or creating a new one. I just had a thought that I might be able to check for the existence of ID in the querystring...

Comment: you can do it via xsl import, declare your variable before you import the xsl file.